# White and black, white and black?

Tags: cipher, visual

Can you find what comes in place of ???

[image]

Hint:

> White + Black = ???

Comment: There's potentially not enough information here to be sure an answer is correct. In other words, there may be more than one potentially valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution could be:

> FA3

Because ...

> In the 3rd step the 0 becomes an A, and 'd' becomes a 'b', maybe it gets mirrored on its y - axis. Also in the 3rd step, C returns in place of E.

But this only a guess, there could be more than one answer.

Another answer could be:

> F_3, because if you overlap C and d with XOR you get A.

Comment: 0, D and E are unchanged i.e., there is a particular character associated with each of them. It can be found by comparing 1st and 2nd correspondences.